# Angular Type Definitions for Unit Tests Not Recognized by VSCode

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, jasmine

## Issue

I have an Angular 9 app and just added a small unit test to a component. But VSCode doesn't recognize the types like `describe`, `beforeEach`, `it`. Although I have a [tsconfig.spec.json](https://github.com/flolu/cents-ideas/blob/45bda5235f832ab801d6439d0179dd6c0e76c4cc/services/client/src/tsconfig.spec.json) file which has `jasmine` in its `types` definition:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": ["jasmine", "node", "jest"]
  },
  "files": ["src/test.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

The actual error I get is the following:

```
Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.ts(2582)
```

[image: types not found]

## What I've tried (but didn't work)

1. Reinstall `@types/jasmine` via `yarn add -D @types/jasmine`
2. Add `jasmine` to `types` of [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/flolu/cents-ideas/blob/45bda5235f832ab801d6439d0179dd6c0e76c4cc/services/client/src/tsconfig.json)
3. Remove the `types` definitions from [tsconfig.spec.json](https://github.com/flolu/cents-ideas/blob/45bda5235f832ab801d6439d0179dd6c0e76c4cc/services/client/src/tsconfig.spec.json)
4. Reinstall all the dependencies of my project
5. Add `jasmine` to `types` of the [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/flolu/cents-ideas/blob/45bda5235f832ab801d6439d0179dd6c0e76c4cc/tsconfig.json) in the root of my monorepo

## Try it yourself

If you want to take a closer look you can try it yourself by

```
git clone https://github.com/flolu/cents-ideas
git checkout 45bda5235f832ab801d6439d0179dd6c0e76c4cc
```

Then `/services/client/src/app/hello-world/hello-world.component.spec.ts` is the file with the errors

**Sidenote:** The test passes, so it is just a problem with VSCode not finding the types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My tsconfig.spec.json was alright. Just had to fix the `typeRoots` path in my tsconfig.json from

```
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
```

to

```
"typeRoots": ["../../node_modules/@types"]
```

because in my monorepo I only have on node_modules folder in the root of the project.

Answer (score 3):

Please try importing

```
  import {} from 'jasmine';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error.
By default the configuration of Angular load the packages @types/***
However, we can configure to load a few package, like "jasmine" for axample.

For that, on file tsconfig.json you must ensure that you add the package dans the parameter "types", or you can delete it and configure "jasmine" or "jest" in tsconfig.spec.json

Extract tsconfig.spec.json  :

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
   "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
   "types": [
  "jasmine"
   ]
  },
```

For me, for me, I advise you not to put "types" in tsconfig.json